# Server always adds suffix to url

Tags: linux, wordpress, .htaccess, centos, suffix

I was playing around with wordpress on my linux machine, and now I am stuck as when i call the ip address on any browser `xxx.xxx.xxx` it always gets redirected to `xxx.xxx.xxx/wordpress` which was a directory below /var/www/html/ where i put all the wordpress files. I must somehow damaged my httpd conf / .htaccess or anything in between. I am not very experienced in those areas, thats why I ask you guys.

How can i disable the permanent addition of a suffix to my systems default url?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please post the code you changed so we can look at it! Preferably your htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any Virtual Hosts added to your **httpd conf**. If yes try removing it